# Git Workflow with Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm looking at using bitbucket to allow for easy updating of a web application and deployment to the production server.

Is it standard practice to continue on a git repo and then when ready to deploy (to either production or development for testing), you deploy from your local computer rather then bitbucket? So in effect, the person deploying would need to update (download from bitbucket) their local repo and then commit to the development server's repo?

Despite the extensive reading on this issue, its still a little unclear.

Thanks

Comment: If your workflow allows it, I think using branches is a much cleaner solution. You can have the server use the bitbucket repo, but only use a "production" branch. When you want to deploy to the server, you merge the branch you're developing in into the "production" branch, and have the server pull that branch (with a git hook for example, which bitbucket can handle).

Comment: Do you plan to update a lot? Or just once every week/month? In the latter case, you can also take advantage of tags. When ready, tag the version, log into server and checkout the tag form bitbucket. If you plan to automate that, @Dettorer's idea would be better for auto-tracking (e.g. using cron).